# Get Kendo UI model from drag and drop on non-Kendo UI widget

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a prototype that uses Kendo UI Pro. It will heavily require the use of the [TreeListView](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index) and Drag and Drop. I've had to create a custom drop location that's using an Angular 1.x custom directive. In this directive's `link` method, I'm binding to the element using `kendoDropTarget()`. I was hoping that by using this method, that I would get the Kendo model associated with the dropped tree row for free, but that does not seem to be the case (unless I just don't know where to look.)

I tried to set and get the `dataTransfer` on the object using the info found from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#Identify_what_is_draggable) like so:

```js
$scope.treeListOptions = {
  //...
  drag: function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(e.source));
   }
};
```

And in my directive, something like:

```
app.directive('dropLoc', function () {
    return {
    // ...
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
        ele.kendoDropTarget({
            dragenter: function (e) {
                var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

But the above just results in an `e.dataTransfer is undefined` error.

So, my question is how can I *receive* the model from a Kendo-enabled widget?

Do I need to wire up a bunch of `data-` attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around my problem here, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this. I think the initial issue is that I'm working within two different scopes: the directive, and the treelist. Being an Angular newb probably doesn't help either. =/

Since I was able to get the drop events to fire, and the source end had the data, I thought I would just create an Angular service to update the data and the source drop event, and then on the target drop event, pull in the new data from the service. This worked until I realized that the target drop event would fire *before* the source drop event.

I worked around this by creating a new event that would be emitted only after the data was updated, and listened to by the target to pull in the data.

I realize this is an older library, but I hate to think that with all of its bells and whistles, that I had to fight so hard to get this to work.